# How can I add several UIStepper Values to one Label?

Tags: swift, label, addition, uistepper

I'm working right now on my first Swift project. I've got 2 stepper and one label - both stepper are sending their values to it. How can I add the value of the second stepper to the label, in which the value of the first stepper is already? Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    stepper.wraps = true
    stepper.autorepeat = true
    stepper.maximumValue = 10000
    stepper2.wraps = true
    stepper2.autorepeat = true
    stepper2.maximumValue = 10000

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
    valueLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
}



@IBOutlet weak var stepper2: UIStepper!
@IBAction func stepper2ValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
    valueLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
}
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: I have tried your code and everything works. The steppers write their values into the ONE label. What exactly do you want? Do want to have BOTH values at the same time in your label? Separated by Space, Komma, ... OR do you want just to have ONE value in the label, then it already works.

Comment: And one line of code is - from my point of view - little bit strange:
valueLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description -> 
This converts a Float into a Int and then into a String via 'description'. You can simply do this (convert the float directly into a String):   
valueLabel.text = String(sender.value)

Comment: i want to get a sum of both values in one label!

Comment: oh haha, alright. gonna try this then. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the two values to ONE String and show this String on your Label, than you have to create a new function that does this for you. I added such a function to your code:`

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    stepper.wraps = true
    stepper.autorepeat = true
    stepper.maximumValue = 10000
    stepper2.wraps = true
    stepper2.autorepeat = true
    stepper2.maximumValue = 10000

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {

    // valueLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
    addValuesToASumAndPutItIntoTheLabel()
}

@IBOutlet weak var stepper2: UIStepper!
@IBAction func stepper2ValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {

    // valueLabel.text = String(sender.value)
    addValuesToASumAndPutItIntoTheLabel()

}

func addValuesToASumAndPutItIntoTheLabel() {
    let summe : Int = Int(stepper.value + stepper2.value)
    valueLabel.text = summe.description
}
```

}`

Comment: ah really great. thank you. love it. it's right that, what i just needed.